# CssResource examples?

Tags: gwt

I am migrating to the use of the `CssResource`.
However, I don't understand how to use prefixed styles :(... Something like:

```css
.prefix .label {
 padding: 10px;
}

.prefix .button {
 padding: 20px;
}
```

How must I transform this to the `CssResource` classes and use it in code :(...
I was playing with `@Import` and `@ImportedWithPrex`, `@Share`, but it's all a bit confusing and the documentation is hard to understand :(...
Please some help ?

Ed

Comment: I've run into this same problem where I've got .myClass {...} and .myClass .gwt-Label {...}. I want to transform this to CssResource, but .gwt-Label is causing problems

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that demonstrates usage of ImportedWithPrefix annotation

```java
 interface Bundle extends ClientBundle {
    @Source("CssImportScopeSample.css")
    InnerStyle innerStyle();

    @Source("CssImportScopeSample.css")
    OuterStyle style();
  }

  @ImportedWithPrefix("inner")
  interface InnerStyle extends Style {
  }

  @ImportedWithPrefix("outer")
  interface OuterStyle extends Style {
  }

  interface Style extends CssResource {
    String body();
  }
```

And a small UiBinder code..

```xml
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' >
  <ui:with field='bundle' type='com.google.gwt.uibinder.test.client.CssImportScopeSample.Bundle' />

  <ui:style import='com.google.gwt.uibinder.test.client.CssImportScopeSample.OuterStyle
        com.google.gwt.uibinder.test.client.CssImportScopeSample.InnerStyle'>
    .outer-body .inner-body { width: 100px; background-color: red; }   
  </ui:style>

  <div class='{bundle.style.body}'> 
    <span ui:field='outer'/>
    <div ui:field='inner' class='{bundle.innerStyle.body}'>Inner!</div>
  </div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Hope this get's you on the right track....

Comment: Thanks, but can you answer my specific case as yours is very different.
I don't understand how to use the style ".prefix .button" in my code.